# Run Airflow Dag only once

Tags: python, airflow

I am looking to create `@once` run for airflow but it doesn't get triggered. Here is my configuration.

```
default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                'start_date': datetime(2020, 5, 1),
                'email': ['your_email@somecompany.com'],
                'email_on_failure': False,
                'email_on_retry': False
                }

dag = DAG('airflow_spark_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='@once',
          catchup=False
          )
```

Even tried using this command `airflow unpause airflow_spark_dag`

I am using airflow v1.10.12.

The list_dag_run is empty and there is no error. Changing schedule_interval to `@hourly` works but not `@once`